# Shell scripts in sendmail aliases

Tags: sendmail

I'm trying to execute a sendmail alias script using this

```
# aliases for my system
addressx:        |sh /usr/share/scripts/myscript.sh  WON'T WORK
addressx:        '/usr/share/scripts/myscript.sh'  WON'T WORK
addressx:        '|/usr/share/scripts/myscripts.sh'  WON'T WORK
```

Can I execute scripts or it must be a binary file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sendmail uses a restricted shell to execute. You have to put programs that Sendmail can execute in the /etc/smrsh directory. You can find out more about this [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap22sec182.html).

You should of course also ensure that the execute bit is set appropriately on that script, and that it is world readable (but not world writable).

Comment: worked perfectly. Shit! never saw such a complicated config file like the sendmail.cf
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `P=` equate shows which shell is used to execute piped delivery.  This is typically either `/usr/bin/smrsh` or `/bin/sh`.  You should use whichever one meets your needs. `/bin/sh` is less persnickety but is less secure.  `/usr/bin/smrsh` is more secure but has rules.

You don't need to do something like `|sh myscript.sh`, the shell is identified in the sendmail configuration.

You can execute scripts as well as binary files, BTW.